# Cloudflare - Unable to send email

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, cloudflare

I am unable to send emails after setting up Cloudflare. I have created an A record mail.example.com and an MX record as example.com.
When I receive emails it works just fine, but when the server sends email I get the error:

```
to=<john.doe@example.no>, relay=ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.205.26]:25, delay=0.58, delays=0.05/0.01/0.45/0.07, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM[74.125.205.26] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist.
```

However, the strange part is that the to-field does not even contain a gmail-address. So why is google even try to resolve it to an gmail-user?
What can be the problem to this issue? DNS-setup og Postfix?

If I send email to gmail-accounts it works fine. But to any other domains it seems that google just bounces it since it expects an gmail-address.

EDIT:

main.cf (editet values that can identify the server):

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
disable_vrfy_command = yes
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = $myhostname, mail.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 xxx.xxx.xxx.xx
myorigin = $mydomain
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost = myhost.com
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_helo_required = yes
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

master.cf:

```
smtp       inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
pickup     unix  n       -       y       60      1       pickup
cleanup    unix  n       -       y       -       0       cleanup
qmgr       unix  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
tlsmgr     unix  -       -       y       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite    unix  -       -       y       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce     unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
defer      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
trace      unix  -       -       y       -       0       bounce
verify     unix  -       -       y       -       1       verify
flush      unix  n       -       y       1000?   0       flush
proxymap   unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
proxywrite unix  -       -       n       -       1       proxymap
smtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
relay      unix  -       -       y       -       -       smtp
showq      unix  n       -       y       -       -       showq
error      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
retry      unix  -       -       y       -       -       error
discard    unix  -       -       y       -       -       discard
local      unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual    unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp       unix  -       -       y       -       -       lmtp
anvil      unix  -       -       y       -       1       anvil
scache     unix  -       -       y       -       1       scache
maildrop   unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
uucp       unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
ifmail     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=Fq. user=bsmtp argv=/usr/lib/bsmtp/bsmtp -t$nexthop -f$sender $recipient
scalemail-backend unix - n       n       -       2       pipe flags=R user=scalemail argv=/usr/lib/scalemail/bin/scalemail-store ${nexthop} ${user} ${extension}
mailman    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe flags=FR user=list argv=/usr/lib/mailman/bin/postfix-to-mailman.py ${nexthop} ${user}
```

Comment: When asking about postfix problems, please include the relevant maillog lines and output of the following command: `postconf -n` (non-default content of main.cf) and `postconf -M` (content of master.cf)

Comment: @HBruijn Thanks for your reply, I have added the information above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the setting `relayhost = host.example.com` you set the next-hop destination of non-local mail; i.e. rather than delivering email messages directly to their destination you instruct postfix that it can simply hand over all messages to a *relay server* (sometimes called a *"smart host"*) that should do the actual delivery.

By default `relayhost` is not set and postfix will (try to) deliver mail directly to the recipient.

Typically your Postfix server needs to be authorised by the relayhost before that server will accept your messages. That authorisation is frequently an ip-address based whitelist or you need to supply credentials.

When your mails get bounced either you are not authorized on the relayhost, or that relayhost is not configured correctly.

Comment: Removed relayhost which fixed the problem. Thanks!